# How to check 'selected' of an item in JCheckBoxTree after pressing the button

Tags: java, swing, jtree, jcheckbox, defaultmutabletreenode

I have a customised JCheckBoxTree which its code is taken from this [source](https://github.com/aterai/java-swing-tips/blob/master/FileSystemTreeWithCheckBox/src/java/example/MainPanel.java).
So I want to have access to the status of each CheckBox of this tree. For example, I want to set an item of the tree as 'SELECTED' by pressing a button. I think I need to make a loop to go through the `DefaultMutableTreeNode` and if the node file is equal to the specified file/string then change its state to `SELECTED`. However I am not sure if it is the right way of doing such a thing and also could not achieve it.

This is what I tried, (doesn't work):

```
public void finder(DefaultMutableTreeNode root){
        JTreeModification treeClass = new JTreeModification();
        Enumeration en = root.depthFirstEnumeration();
        //if(){}
        while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) en.nextElement();
            if(node.equals("file4.json")){
               treeClass.new CheckBoxNode(new File(node.getParent(), node), JTreeModification.Status.SELECTED);
            }
        }
}
```

The following lines are related codes from my main file:

```
        JTreeModification treeClass = new JTreeModification();
        File myTest = new File("D:\\Documents\\A X");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode();
        final DefaultTreeModel treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(root);

        for (File fileSystemRoot: myTest.listFiles()) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(treeClass.new CheckBoxNode(fileSystemRoot, JTreeModification.Status.DESELECTED));
            root.add(node);
        }
        treeModel.addTreeModelListener(treeClass.new CheckBoxStatusUpdateListener());
        final JTree tree = new JTree(treeModel) {
            @Override public void updateUI() {
                setCellRenderer(null);
                setCellEditor(null);
                super.updateUI();
                //???#1: JDK 1.6.0 bug??? Nimbus LnF
                setCellRenderer(treeClass.new FileTreeCellRenderer());
                setCellEditor(treeClass.new CheckBoxNodeEditor());
            }
        };
        tree.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));
        tree.setRootVisible(false);
        tree.addTreeSelectionListener(treeClass.new FolderSelectionListener());

        tree.setEditable(true);
        tree.expandRow(0);

        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        panel.add(new JScrollPane(tree), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Here is the class that I think is related to my issue:

```
public enum Status { SELECTED, DESELECTED, INDETERMINATE }

class CheckBoxNode {
        public final File file;
        public Status status;
        public CheckBoxNode(File file) {
            this.file = file;
            status = Status.INDETERMINATE;
        }
        public CheckBoxNode(File file, Status status) {
            this.file = file;
            this.status = status;
        }
        @Override public String toString() {
            return file.getName();
        }
}
```

In the provided GitHub link, there is method starting from line 72, that does something similar to what I want, but I could not merge it to my method.

So is there any idea about how to change the status of a tree's item programatically ?

**EDIT:**

```
public void finder(DefaultMutableTreeNode root){
        JTreeModification treeClass = new JTreeModification();
        Object o = root.getLastChild();
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) o;
        o = node.getUserObject();
        CheckBoxNode check = (CheckBoxNode) o;
        System.out.println(check);
        if(check.toString().equals("Video1.avi")){
            check.status = JTreeModification.Status.SELECTED; 
            //treeModel.addTreeModelListener(treeClass.new CheckBoxStatusUpdateListener());
        }
        System.out.println(check.status);

        Enumeration e = node.children();
            while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
                finder(root);
        }
    }
```

I just noticed the above code can assign "SELECTED" to the first file of the iteration if its name is same as the one in the if statement. (`Video1.avi`) in this example. So I am sure `check.status = JTreeModification.Status.SELECTED;` can do the job. But there are two problems still, first it does not loop all over the nodes. and secondly, although it assigns `Selected` to the file and I could recognise that in the console print, but it does not show it in the UI until I check or press another item in the tree then it updates the ui and set `Video1.avi`. So it needs to loop all over the nodes and update the UI.

Comment: How are you assessing the nodes?  You could iterate over the tree model through the use of a recursive algorithm and return all the selected items...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Do you mean assigning files to the DefaultMutableTreeNode? If so, `for (File fileSystemRoot: myTest.listFiles()) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(treeClass.new CheckBoxNode(fileSystemRoot, JTreeModification.Status.DESELECTED));
            root.add(node);
        }` does this. As it seems!

Comment: I more curious about how you were iterating through the tree nodes...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Well I am not sure if I get you correctly, but the first piece of code in my question is what I meant by iterating the tree model, but obviously it is not functioning, since CheckBoxNode takes a file in its constructor. (If that is the only problem).

Comment: The question would then be, how could `DefaultMutableTreeNode` ever be equal to `file4.json`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer well, I printed node in the loop and it was printing the name of files and folders. so I thought it can easily find the file that is equal to `file4.json`.

Comment: `DefaultMutableTreeNode` `toString` (from memory) is using the `userObject` properties `toString` result...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I made an update in my post. Please have a look. I think I am getting closer to the solution.